# cordova-plugin-local-notifications on click is not working if redirection added

Tags: cordova

**plugin: katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.**

The notification and 'on click ' event works properly but if we add redirection after schedule , 'on click' event is not firing...
This is my send reminder function..

```
     function add_reminder(notify_list){
        cordova.plugins.notification.local.hasPermission(function(granted){
           if(granted == true){
              cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule(notify_list);
           }else{
      cordova.plugins.notification.local.registerPermission(function(granted) {
        if(granted == true){
           cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule(notify_list);
        }else{
           navigator.notification.alert("Reminder cannot be added because app doesn't have permission");
        }
      });
     }
    }); 
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification, state) {
       alert(notification.id + " was clicked");
       window.localStorage.setItem("not_sch_id",notification.id);

       window.location.href='main.html';
    }, this);

}
```

And the calling code is..

```
var sch_not_list=[];
msg="You have medication(s) to take now 00:00 XX" ;
var schedule_time = new Date(('2015-12-16 14:48:00').replace(/-/g, "/")).getTime();
sch_not_list.push({id: 14,title: 'Medicine Reminder',text: msg,at: schedule_time});

add_reminder(sch_not_list);
//..following line causes onclick not working
window.location.href = "main.html";
```

...From above code if i remove the last "window.location.href = "main.html"; " the notification and the click event fires properly.

Can you please guide me on this?